# Combine data from two different API's into one JSON file in a Sveltekit app?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

So essentially I have movie data that's coming in from two different API's. Endpoint #1 has simple movie data (the IMDB ID, a specific rating related to the API I'm calling from, and the movie title). I'm using the IMDB ID from endpoint #1 to filter and get the rest of the data (movie image, link, etc) from endpoint #2.

Additionally, I can only call data from the first endpoint a limited number of times so as to not overload its fragile server, so I want this combined data dumped into a JSON file once a day that my app can then reference.

So I believe I'd need to run a CRON job to get this data at a certain interval, but what tools could I then use to combine the data into a JSON file?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share code, and give it as text not as photo or video file, or another internal link, edit your question